# Best way to overlay two lists and tell where insertions have occured

Tags: python

I'm looking for a pretty niche algorithm that will allow me to overlay two lists in Python and describe to me where insertions have occurred. I'm a little perplexed at the best way to do this. Here is my example:

Since the two sets: ("cms", "example", "1", "dev", "product") and ("cms", "example", "product") have a majority of matching elements (3 matching to 2 non matching) my script will try to compare them. What I would like it to be able to do is overlay the two list and tell at which index which insertions occurred. Like this:

```
("cms", "example",             "product")
("cms", "example", "1", "dev", "product")
```

Should return something like (("1", "dev"), 2) because "1" and "dev" were both inserted at index 2.

It should be able to handle multiple insertions. For example:

```
("cms",      "example"         "product")
("cms", "1", "example", "dev", "product")
```

will return ((("1"), 1), (("dev"), 2)) because "1" was inserted at index 1 and "dev" was inserted at index 2 (of the original string).

Any ideas on how to do this efficiently? I'm stumped.

Comment: How do you expect the algorithm to deal with ambiguous insertions? For example, if you have `('a', 'a')` and `('a', 'a', 'a')`, which of the three `'a'`s is the new one? Also, are insertions the only changes you expect to the lists? Or do you need to deal with deletions or other modifications as well?

Comment: I was about to suggest that the OP use sets, subtract one from the other, and obtain the index of elements existent in one but not the other set. However, @Grismar's question will have to be answered first since this approach doesn't work with repeated elements.

Comment: You're asking how to do this efficiently, but not even providing a naive solution?

Comment: In addition to @Grismar what would you do with `(a, b, a, c, d, a, c, e)` and `(a, b, a, c, e)` ? You probably want to use difflib https://medium.com/boring-tech/python-programming-the-standard-library-difflib-28ffaf5c1155

Comment: Another issue of ambiguity is this: if you have `('a', 'a')` and `('a', 'b', 'c', 'a')`, do you expect the result to be `((('b', 'c'), 1))`? Or `((('b'), 1), (('c'), 1))` as both have been inserted at position 1, one after the other? Or  possibly `((('b'), 1), (('c'), 2))`, although that seems unlikely, as you seem to reference the original positions in your example.

Comment: Wow - great questions guys. This case will not happen in my use cases, so I didn't think it through. In the case of ('a', 'a', 'a'), the 'a' should be inserted at the end. @Grismar

Comment: @Sadap, your comparison would be d,a,c inserted at index 4.

Comment: @Grismar, in the case above, I would like the insertions at a specific index to be grouped, so the result would be (((b,c), 1))

Comment: Justing Gardner and why not `a, c, d` at index 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this meets your expectations:

```
def find_insertions(before, after):
    j = 0
    for i, x in enumerate(before):
        inserts = []
        while after[j] != x:
            inserts.append(after[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            j += 1
        if inserts:
            yield inserts, i
    if j < len(after):
        yield len(before), after[j:]


list1 = ["cms", "example", "product"]
list2 = ["cms", "1", "example", "dev", "product"]

print(list(find_insertions(list1, list2)))
# assumes lazy inserts, last possible position is returned
print(list(find_insertions(['a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a'])))
# assumes grouped inserts
print(list(find_insertions(['a', 'a'], ['a', 'b', 'b', 'a'])))
# given example in comments
print(list(find_insertions(['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e'], ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'c', 'e'])))
```

Results:

```
[(['1'], 1), (['dev'], 2)]
[(2, ['a'])]
[(['b', 'b'], 1)]
[(['d', 'a', 'c'], 4)]
```

By the way: it's expected you provide your own solution and ask questions about it. Don't expect StackOverflow to write your code for you, even though often the answer will completely replace your own efforts, showing you put the work in goes a long way. Also, you learn more.

Comment: thanks for your solution. I'll keep in mind your suggestion above and write a more naive solution next time. I've certainly put effort into it, I assure you. And I really appreciate your elegant solution!

Comment: I figured as much from your answers - so the warning was mostly directed at anyone else that finds the answer and at those that (rightly) pointed it out previously :)

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
insertions = []
for j, x in enumerate(list1):
    inserted = []
    while x != list2[i]:
        inserted.append(list2[i])
        i +=1
    if inserted:
        insertions.append((inserted, j))
    i += 1
```